# Subquery problem when using WHERE in secondary SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem with query.

```
SELECT 
    a.code,
    b.codename,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.IdNum)
     FROM 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM NumTable
          WHERE YEAR(DateOfPoint) = 2019)) AS CountNumber
FROM 
    NumTable b
JOIN
    CodeTable a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.SellYear IS NOT NULL
```

My First question is about CountNumber is it ok ? I need to count only those b.IdNum that have DateOfPoint = 2019. It should only be to this field not to any other in this query, thats why I didn't use it in the end in WHERE.
Second question is about CountNumber too becouse I still get error msg that I got there incorrect syntax I was looking for it for about hour and couldn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: The subquery should probably be _correlated_, i.e. include a reference to the outer query.

Comment: 2. Subqueries in the `FROM` need aliases; yours doesn't have one. 1. No, your `WHERE` isn't SARGable; use explicit date boundaries with `>=` and `<`.

Comment: 3. "b" is for "NumTable", "a" is for "CodeTable"? Not in my alphabet book. Use *meaningful* aliases. "N" (or "NT") is for "NumTable", "C" (or "CT") is for "CodeTable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to get here but I think group by is more logicly here

```
SELECT a.code
,b.codename
,Sum(case when b.DateOfPoint= 2019 then 1 else 0) as CountNumber
FROM NumTable b
JOIN CodeTable a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.SellYear IS NOT NULL
group by a.code,b.codename
```

you will get a row for each  code and codename and the number of dateofPoint in 2019 that it have if there are none it will return 0

Comment: I used your code and changed it a bit
`
SELECT a.code
,b.codename
,(case when b.DateOfPoint= 2019 then COUNT(b.IdNum) else 0) as CountNumber
FROM NumTable b
JOIN CodeTable a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.SellYear IS NOT NULL
group by a.code,b.codename
`
And it's worked I think it was all about it, thanks I should use CASE earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query. I think, it will work for you:

```
SELECT a.code, 
    b.codename
    FROM
    NumTable b
    JOIN
    CodeTable a ON a.id = b.id
    JOIN
    (SELECT * 
              FROM NumTable
              WHERE YEAR(DateOfPoint) = 2019) c ON c.id = b.id
    JOIN
    (SELECT id, COUNT(b.IdNum) FROM c) d ON c.id = d.id
    WHERE 
        a.SellYear IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT c.code, n.codename, c.cnt_2019
FROM (SELECT n.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DateOfPoint) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2019
      FROM NumTable n
     ) n JOIN
     CodeTable c
     ON c.id = n.id
WHERE c.SellYear IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that I also changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table names rather than arbitrary letters.